# Jenkins: Is there a way to change the job description post run?

Tags: jenkins

I'm currently editing the Jenkins' job description using a function in my jenkinsfile:

```
currentBuild.description = "${get_user_name()} bla bla"
```

I want, after the build is done, to read a pytest html file (which is generated during the job) and extract number of passed / failed tests, and add that data to the description.

The extraction itself is already done in  a python script I have, however, I'm not sure how can I add that data to the description.

One way I thought of was an http request to the jenkins web API, but that seems a bit convoluted, and specifically, I had some problems doing that in the past.

Is there a way to make it simple using http, or using another (built-in) way?

Comment: You can store the output of the Python script in a Groovy variable, for example, `testResults = sh (script: "python extract_results.py", returnStdout: true).trim()`. Then use this variable in the build description.

Comment: Yeah, but the groovy script is called only at the job's start. The data is obtained at the end

Comment: Could you please elaborate this? You can set the build description as a post step?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible as the description is a global variable, and changing it post build does nothing because it will not be ready from the web API, AFAIK